# How does the Fama and French 3-factor model explain stock covariance?

Tags: finance, asset-pricing, corporate-finance

Does it at all? If so, how?

It is understood that size and value play a role in determining returns and there are proposed explanation those these, but what about covariance?

Comment: You should include more content in your question -like describe the model you are talking about, if not writing it out mathematically, provide a link to where it is presented-discussed more extensively etc. "Help us help you", it is called

Comment: I was assuming that someone with relevant the finance knowledge would be rather familiar with the 3-factor model and could therefore put in there 2 sense.

Comment: That's a kind thought, but no model is so engraved in stone that by just saying "3-factor model" even those with the relevant financial knowledge would know exactly what you are referring to -in fact, those people will exactly be the ones that they will clearly know that under every "model label", many variants are hosted.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways I could think of to answer this question. First, and I think this is what you are asking, "what is the covariance structure of two assets under the [Fama-French 3-factor model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fama%E2%80%93French_three-factor_model)?" Consider two assets $i$ and $j$.

Let's start with their returns under the Fama-French factor model:
$$ r_{i,t} = \alpha_{i} + \beta_{1,i} MKT_{t} + \beta_{2,i} HML_{t}+ \beta_{3,i}SMB_{t} + \epsilon_{i,t}$$
$$ r_{j,t} = \alpha_{j} + \beta_{1,j} MKT_{t} + \beta_{2,j} HML_{t}+ \beta_{3,j}SMB_{t} + \epsilon_{j,t}$$
Under the assumptions of the factor model setup:

1. $Cov(\epsilon_{j,t}, \epsilon_{i,t}) = 0$
2. $E[\epsilon_{j,t}]=E[\epsilon_{i,t}]=0$
3. $Var(\epsilon_{k,t})=\sigma^2_{\epsilon_{k}}, \forall k $
4. $Var(MKT_{t})=\sigma^2_{M}$
5. $Var(HML_{t})=\sigma^2_{H}$
6. $Var(SMB_{t})=\sigma^2_{S}$
7. The covariance of two factors is $Cov(F_{k},F_{\ell})=\sigma_{k,\ell}$ for $k\neq\ell$
8. All alphas and betas are constants

Now let's estimate the covariance of the returns when $i\neq j$:

$$ Cov(r_{i,t}, r_{j,t})  = Cov(\alpha_{i} + \beta_{1,i} MKT_{t} + \beta_{2,i} HML_{t}+ \beta_{3,i}SMB_{t}, \\ \alpha_{j} + \beta_{1,j} MKT_{t} + \beta_{2,j} HML_{t}+ \beta_{3,j}SMB_{t} + \epsilon_{j,t})$$
Recall that $ Cov(aX+bY,cW+dZ) = \\ ac \cdot Cov(X,W) + bc \cdot Cov(Y,W)\\ + ad \cdot Cov(X,Z) + bd \cdot Cov(Y,Z)$

These assumptions imply that
$$ Cov(r_{i,t}, r_{j,t}) = 
\beta_{i,1} \beta_{j,1} \sigma^2_{M} + \\
\beta_{i,1} \beta_{j,2} \sigma_{M,H} + \\
\beta_{i,1} \beta_{j,3} \sigma_{M,S} + \\
\beta_{i,2} \beta_{j,1} \sigma_{M,H} + \\
\beta_{i,2} \beta_{j,2} \sigma^2_{H} + \\
\beta_{i,2} \beta_{j,3} \sigma_{H,S} + \\
\beta_{i,3} \beta_{j,1} \sigma_{M,S} + \\
\beta_{i,3} \beta_{j,2} \sigma_{H,S} + \\
\beta_{i,3} \beta_{j,3} \sigma^2_{S}  \\
= \beta_{i,1} \beta_{j,1} \sigma^2_{M} + \beta_{i,2} \beta_{j,2} \sigma^2_{H} +  \beta_{i,3} \beta_{j,3} \sigma^2_{S} + 
(\beta_{i,1} \beta_{j,2} + \beta_{i,2} \beta_{j,1}) \sigma_{M,H} + 
(\beta_{i,1} \beta_{j,3} + \beta_{i,3} \beta_{j,1})  \sigma_{M,S} + 
(\beta_{i,2} \beta_{j,3}  + \beta_{i,3} \beta_{j,2} ) \sigma_{H,S} 
$$
And a $Var(r_{k}) = $
$$ \beta_{k,1}^2 \sigma^2_{M} + \beta_{k,2}^2\sigma^2_{H} +  \beta_{k,3}^2 \sigma^2_{S} + 
2\beta_{k,1} \beta_{k,2} \sigma_{M,H} + 
2\beta_{k,1} \beta_{k,3}  \sigma_{M,S} + 
2\beta_{k,2} \beta_{k,3} \sigma_{H,S} + \sigma^2_{\epsilon_{k}}$$

The alternative question might be "why would assets follow the data generating process that is found in Fama-French". I'm not sure that there is a good answer to that. Factor models are nice and convenient, and Fama and French developed theirs to match the observation that historically small caps and stocks with a high book-to-market ratio have out performed. That wasn't really a theory argument, although it is probably possible to write down a theory model where asset prices follow a Fama French 3-factor process, I don't know of any. One paper says:

> Fama  & French (1993) contend  that stock returns can be described by
> three  factors,  viz,  market,  size  and  book-to-market  equity.
> However, the  model  lacks  any  well-built  academic  justification
> as  to  why  size and    book-to-market    describe    the  cross-sectional    differences    in predicted  returns  of  stocks.

[AN EMPIRICAL EXAMINATION OF THE FAMA-FRENCH MODEL IN INDIA](http://ir.amu.ac.in/12126/1/T10528.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to what covariance this question refers to.

As in the CAPM model the covariance among assets is reduced to $\beta$, through the covariance with the market index.

$\beta_i=\sigma_{i,M}/\sigma_M^2$

Then, if CAPM is correct, we could explain the covariance relating the $\beta$s

$\sigma_{i,j}=\beta_i*\beta_j*\sigma_M^2$

In the context of multifactor models something similar occurs, since, in order to use those models, it is necessary to estimate $\beta$s, or sensitivities, related to each proposed factors.